# Converting string into a readable int from a JLabel

Tags: java, type-conversion, parseint, numberformatexception

I need to apply an interest method to a number in a JLabel. I can manage to do it from a Jtextfield, but for some reason I cannot get it to work on the JLabel.

**Here is the code that is initiated when the Jbutton is pressed:**

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    interest(Integer.parseInt(balanceLabel.getText()));
```

balanceLabel is the name of the label I am trying to work with.

**Here is the error that is returned when I press the button:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "£1000.0"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

I have researched the problem and it seems it is extremely common but for some reason I cannot apply other answers to my situation as I lack the knowledge to do so.

Comment: you must eliminate  £ sign before parsing the string to Integer

Comment: Any idea how I can get rid of it just whilst it reads what is in the JLabel?

Comment: Amazing answers. I appreciate the time and knowledge you have all put into helping me. With that said, I did decide to use "Float" instead of "Double" as @dambros said. Both answers from Lasagna and dambros should be considered by other users with a similar problem as they are extremely informative. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `£` AND the `.` since you are trying an int conversion.

Use a float instead:

```
Float.parseFloat(balanceLabel.getText().substring(1));
```

This way you can have decimal values, which makes sense for currency.

Comment: Great answer! It is all clear now. I cannot believe I didn't think of that DARN DECIMAL POINT! I thought it was just the "£" that was making it show as an error. Thanks for your time and knowledge. This includes all the other users that helped towards this answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Well, from what I can see you are trying to convert '£' which isn't an integer, so you are getting an exception for that.  You also have a decimal value, which an integer cannot handle, so the exception is also being thrown for that reason.

```
public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException
```

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.
>
> Parameters: s - a String containing the int representation to be parsed
>
> Returns: the integer value represented by the argument in decimal.
>
> **Throws:  NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.**

---

what you could do, if you know that everything will be '£xxxx.xx," is you can change this line

```
  interest(Integer.parseInt(balanceLabel.getText()));
```

to this

```
interest(Double.parseDouble(balanceLabel.getText().substring(1));
```

which would then return "1000.0"

```
public String substring(int beginIndex)
```

> Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.
>   Examples:
>
> "unhappy".substring(2) returns "happy"
>
> "Harbison".substring(3) returns "bison"
>
> "emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)
>
> Parameters: beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
>
> Returns: the specified substring.
>
> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the £ sign is essentially the cause of the problem. I tried using your line of code and i get the same error but without the £ in the number. E.g _For input string: "1000.0"_

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I looked at this before going to get some food.   I made an edit, essentially 1000.0 cannot be an integer, it's a Double, so you should change "Integer" to "Double."  Hope this helps, I alos changed my code to reflect this.

Let me know if there are any other issues.

The exception happens because "the string does not contain a parsable integer."

Your interest will either have to supply a Double value, or you will have to get rid of the extra values after the decimal, but it seems you want the decimal value for sure, so go with Doubles.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for your time and knowledge. I really do appreciate it from the heart!

Comment: Sure, no problem, shame I missed that decimal, when you posted your edit I realized that was the issue, but I see someone else figured everything out first, so that's all good :).

Comment: Ah, but your answer taught me how to use substring() which is invaluable.Again, thank you

Comment: great, glad I could help.  There is a few ways to use substring, so I would check them out i.e., s.substring(x,s.length()); to go from x index to the last index of String s.